# How to pass array of JSON objects with Files from Spring Controller?

Tags: java, spring, rest, file, web

I want to have a Spring REST Controller that returns an array of objects containing a file, basically a picture. What I could do is:

1. Create a POJO
2. Get the image and convert to a base 64 string
3. Put this string as a field in the POJO
4. Add this POJO to an ArrayList
5. Repeat steps 1-4 as necessary
6. Attach the ArrayList to the ResponseEntity
7. Send back the response entity to the client
8. From the client, get the file and paint the image in a canvas

or in code, something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getInfo")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getInfo() throws Throwable {

    ArrayList<Object> objList = new ArrayList<Object>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Object obj = new Object();

        obj.setField1(0);
        obj.setField2(0);

        String stringImg = // Convert image to base 64 string

        obj.setStringImg(stringImg);
        objList.add(obj);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(objList, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I've heard that converting and using base 64 string wastes space and is not really best practice. Is there an alternative or better way of doing this?

Comment: Just return the URL and fetch the image as a regular `image/jpeg`?

Comment: The image you want to convert is stored in the file system or is passed through the web service?

Comment: @amicoderozer it's stored in the file system but is passed to the web service.

Comment: @chrylis The image should be a field in a POJO. I have a list of multiple POJOs and I want to send it that way back to the client. How do I get the URL, fetch the image and draw it on a canvas?

Comment: Don't return the POJO directly, use a DTO that provides a URL to it. Spring Data REST, for all its problems, has a `ControllerLinkBuilder` that can help.

Answer (score 0):

You heard right, `Base64` increases file size of **33%** and if you put all the files you want to upload in memory you have an high risk of getting out of memory exception. In my opinion the best way to upload image to Spring web service is to make a method that uploads the image using Spring `MultiPartFile` (this will handle big files for you, storing in file system instead of memory), save it to the database and in another method fetch the image you stored by id or name.

A example of what i mean:

```
public long uploadImage(@RequestParam("file")  MultipartFile file)){
     InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes());
     // save the file to the database as blob or clob
     return file id or name;
}
```

Then in another method fetch the images from database as Blob or Clob, convert it to string, create the list and return it to the client. Creating the list with all files will put the files in memory anyway, but at least you will save **33%** of file size for each file.

Another option is to let the client get one image at time, and let it construct the list with all the files. By the way your choice depends on the images size, and how many users will use this service.